# How to get MEV relay?

Tags: go-ethereum, etherscan, mev-searcher, relay

There are several types of the nodes which support MEV and they are using different relays.
For example, this is Flash-bots node https://etherscan.io/address/0xdafea492d9c6733ae3d56b7ed1adb60692c98bc5
and we can send tx to this node by using https://relay.flashbots.net relay.

What I would like to know is all of these relays.
For example, I searched but I can not get the relay of this node.
https://etherscan.io/address/0x8d5998a27b3cdf33479b65b18f075e20a7aa05b9 (MEV Builder: 0x8D...5b9)

Someone, please help me.
Thanks